# Storage Error - First Depth Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, storage, ada

I'm currently working on a algorithm which should solve a 3D puzzle.
However I've encountered a problem, the algorithm I use is a First Search Depth and it seems to be working well until I get "raised STORAGE_ERROR : EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW". I'm not quite sure why it is not working. Any guesses to why this isn't working?

What I want this algorithm to do: 
It takes a List, a figure, and a goal. For this example the list is 7 parts long. It tries to enter the part in the first coord. If it doesn't fit, it rotates until it does fit, it then calls on it self with the rest (6 parts). If the part rotates all 24 ways (all possible ways to rotate a 3D part) then it moves to another coordinate and starts again with trying to fit. When all the parts are gone or nothing works it should just quit and I have another algorithm that sends in the same list with another order into this algorithm.

I would also like the algorithm to see if the last coordinate doesn't match with the Goal then it should just backtrack and try to find another solution.

Here is some of the code:

```ada
procedure Pseudo(Parts : in out List_Type; Figure : in out Figure_Type; Goal : in out Figure_Type; LastCoord : in out Integer) is
        Unchanged : Part_Type := Parts.Data;
        Next : boolean := False;
        UnchangedFigure : Figure_Type;
    begin
    UnchangedFigure := Figure;
        if Empty(Parts) then
            raise Finished;
        else
            for I in 1..24 loop 
                RotNumber(Parts.Data,I); -- rotera
                if Check(Parts.Data,Figure) then -- test om den platsar
                    Maincheck(Parts.Data,Figure,Goal,Next);
                    if Next then
                        Unchanged := Parts.Data;
                        Append_Part(Parts.Data,Figure);
                        Remove_First(Parts);
                        Next := False;
                        Pseudo(Parts,Figure,Goal,LastCoord);
                        Next := False;
                        Figure := UnchangedFigure;
                        Insert_First(Unchanged,Parts);
                        Figure.CoordX := 0;
                        Figure.CoordY := 0;
                        Figure.CoordZ := 0;
                    end if;
                end if;
                Parts.Data := Unchanged;
            end loop;
        end if;
        -- if LastCoord /= 7 then --(Original 
            -- if To_String(Figure.Data)(LastCoord) /= To_String(Goal.Data)(LastCoord) then
                -- Put("over");
                -- return;
            -- end if;
        -- end if;
        LastCoord := Figure.CoordZ*Figure.X*Figure.Y + (Figure.Y-Figure.CoordY-1)*(Figure.X) + Figure.CoordX +1;
        if Figure.CoordY < Figure.Y-1 then
            Figure.CoordY := Figure.CoordY +1;
            Pseudo(Parts,Figure,Goal,LastCoord);
        elsif Figure.CoordY = Figure.Y-1 then
            if Figure.CoordX < Figure.X-1 then
                Figure.CoordX := Figure.CoordX +1;
                Figure.CoordY := 0;
                Pseudo(Parts,Figure,Goal,LastCoord);
            elsif Figure.CoordX = Figure.X-1 then
                if Figure.CoordZ < Figure.Z-1 then
                    Figure.CoordZ := Figure.CoordZ +1;
                    Figure.CoordX := 0;
                    Figure.CoordY := 0;
                    Pseudo(Parts,Figure,Goal,LastCoord);
                elsif Figure.CoordZ = Figure.Z-1 then
                    return;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end Pseudo;
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I'd suggest you verify that your recursion is properly terminating. Out of control recursion is a trivially easy way to blow the stack and raise a Storage_Error.

Comment: Hello, I think you were right, it was probably a infinite recursion somewhere. However I'm still not quite sure if it works as intended due to the insane amount of possible "branches".

Comment: @user2207734, you need to review the way you are branching then

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use exceptions to control program flow, it's bad practice. Consider using an additional `out` parameter instead of `raise Finished`.

I think it's also an error to declare all parameters as `in out`. Look at `Parts`: In your loop, you append the figure to its `Data` member, then remove the first element of the list. After that, you call `Pseudo` which will mangle with the list again, and if it doesn't succeed, `Parts` will possible have entirely different contents than before the call. You restore the first element after that, but whatever `Append_Part` does stays permanent. I cannot tell for sure if this is actually a problem. The effort to restore the list and the figure after the call to `Pseudo` is also an obvious sign that you do not want these parameters to be `in out`.

Another thing that looks fishy is that after the loop, you change the coordinates of the figure and then call `Pseudo` again - which will reset the coordinates at the end of its first iteration to 0 (if conditions match). A possible control flow will be:

- `Pseudo` starts, `Parts` is not empty. Loop starts. Let's assume that the figure's `Coord` values are initially 0.
- No iteration of the loop leads to `Finished`. Loop ends.
- The algorithm changes some coordinate and calls `Pseudo`. Let's assume for now that `Parts` still has the same value as it had when `Pseudo` was called the first time. As I wrote, this does not seem to be the case, but it should be if I understand your description correctly.
- The second call to `Pseudo` it identical to the first one, except that some coord of the figure differs (and possibly `Last_Coord`, which doesn't seem to matter).
- `Parts` cannot be empty, loop starts.
- Now let's assume that at some point in the loop, conditions match, but the call to `Pseudo` fails (as in "doesn't raise Finished"). Coordinates will be reset to 0.
- From there on, the execution is identical to that of the first `Pseudo` call, because the data it operates on is now identical. So no `Finished` will be raised in the loop, and after that, `Pseudo` will be called a third time with exactly the same parameters as before.

As you see, this will lead to an endless recursion. I cannot tell for sure if this can happen because I don't know anything about your types or the subprograms you call.

In its current condition, your code is hard to understand because it has a very complex control flow. If you take away some of your code's complexity, it will be easier to track down errors. I suggest using loops to iterate over the coordinates rather than recursion. This may solve your problem.